# How to inject value of initParam into managed bean?

Tags: jsf, managed-bean

I have a context-param in web.xml:

```
<context-param>
        <description>Version number will be prefixed to url of requests</description>
        <param-name>version_id</param-name>
        <param-value>11</param-value>
</context-param>
```

I want to inject this into a ManagedBean
This bean has a scope None

I tried the code below but it's not working, I'm getting an exception on startup with this error:

The scope of the object referenced by expression #{initParam[version_id]}, application, is shorter than the referring managed beans (responseData) scope of none

```
@ManagedBean
@NoneScoped
public class ResponseData implements Serializable {


    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{initParam.version_id}")
    private String version;


    public ResponseData() {
    }

    /**
     * @param version the version to set
     */
    public void setVersion(String version) {
        this.version = version;
    }

}
```

What is the right way to inject value of context-param into a managed bean as a managed property?

Answer (score 1):

What you are attempting is that you are trying to get the value of a managed property that has a smaller scope than the ResponseData managed bean that is NoneScoped.

You should be able to get the context params from the `ServletContext` however without needing to reference another bean.

```
ServletContext servletContext = (ServletContext) FacesContext
   .getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getContext();
servletContext.getInitParameter("version_id");
```

Comment: `ExternalContext` has an easier delegate method for that.